# xubuntu 14.04 running slow!

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xubuntu

I did a fresh install of xubuntu 14.04, 64bit, on my Kingston (ssdNOW 300), and OS is running slowly, occasional "temporary" freezes.

Here is my hardware:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 750  @ 2.67GHz, 1197.000 MHz
- FC Gigabyte GA-P55-UD3 motherboard
- G94 nVidia Geforce 9600 GT
- 4GB ram,

I am also using two monitors.

I also have dual boot option, with win8.1 being on physically separate disc.

When I login the whole screen is a bit noisy (random pixels, random colors), for a minute or so. Then the desktop loads and looks fine.

I expected xubuntu to run extremely fast, but it freezes sometimes even during simplest tasks like saving a gedit file, writing some text in the terminal. Applications very often "stop working properly" and want to close. After I click cancel, they continue to work ok... for some time and than freeze again.
I suspected nVidia graphic card, installed drivers from "additional drivers", rebooted and well, the whole thing slowed down even more.

Did anybody have similar issues?

I am getting quite desperate here.

Comment: What version of the proprietary drivers are you using?  Also try updating the BIOS/UEFI just in case.

Comment: Can you try the integrated graphics instead of the Nvidia card

Comment: @user4901968: i am using Vendor: Award Software International, Inc.
 Version: F9
 Release Date: 06/23/2010

Comment: at the moment  i am using: X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau(open source)
In the meantime i switched to nVidia binary driver version 340.96 from nVidia 340(proprietary, tested), but it didnt make much of a difference, so i switched back.

Comment: check `smartctl -l error /dev/sdXY` for disk problems

Comment: @jet there were two errors on a disk i used for windows 8.1, but didnt use it for my xubuntu os. I unplugged the disc and have same problems. Other discs reported no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem was apparently my second hard disc, on which i installed my /home directory. The disc didn't report any errors with smart scan.
Something was wrong with it's response time.

How could i have detected this?
Trial and error saved me this time.

I unmounted my second hard drive just in case, and moved my /home directory to my solid state disc.
It works extremely fast now.

Thanks everybody, for your suggestions and time.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your graphic card install

On screen login: `Alt+Ctrl+F1`

your login and your password

> sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
>
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

```
Alt+Ctrl+F7
```

Comment: +50 Because you tried to find a solution.